# Trying to nest css selectors on a hover

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to run this when a hover occurs - change the background-color of a inner class to grey, can this be done with css?

```css
.thumbnail:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgba(156, 162, 153, 1);
  .labels .inner {
    background-color: rgba(156, 162, 153, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a CSS preprocessor (Sass,SCSS,LESS)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can:

```
.thumbnail:hover {
    border: 2px solid rgba(156, 162, 153, 1);
}

.thumbnail:hover .labels .inner{
    background-color: rgba(156, 162, 153, 1);
}
```

Even your styles will work if you use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)/[LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which will precompile that styles into this ones.

Also, as [@Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) said, this depends of your markup. This will work on the following scenario (one of the):

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="labels">
        <div class="inner">Foobar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/117wf15j/)